# Shrinkwrap around an irregular curve

Tags: python, scripting, hair, shrinkwrap, curve-modifier

I'm attempting to shrinkwrap braids around a head in my blender python program. The braids are guided using small, individual lines I created and shrinkwrap *onto* the head, but the lines won't shrinkwrap **around** the head like cornrows would, no matter how large I make them. Even if hey are larger than the head.
For instance:
[image: ![example 1]

and the shrinkwrap looks like this
[image: ![example 2]

However, I want the braid to follow the shape around the head. Something like actual braids would. Each of these braids is comprised of individual segments so I can use any modifiers on the entire thing or the individual plaits (pieces of the braid).

Any Suggestions?
Here's what I'd like it to look like
[image: good-braid]

Comment: Can you provide the blend file. I think I may have a solution. It's can be easy to not understand it at the first look. But I will look at the model and confirm if it's what I think it is and let you know.

Comment: @Akshay2005 here it is. Thank you for any help [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CPDq7JH4ayQkfPN0tfCJD9amDP3HONvx/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I am extremely sorry. For some reason the fact that this was related to python just went out of my head while reading this. I won't be able to help you with this one.  I did download the file and try to see the problem. I can surely try to help whatever I can. I would give you two major suggestions. First your issue that you are not able to shrink wrap them. The reason behinf that is that in the shrinkwrapping process. the vertex to be shrinkwrapped finds the closest durface on the target mesh. This can be best explained through an image. I will provide a link in the next comment.

Comment: Before shrinkwrapping: https://imgur.com/a/xbogrPg. The left one matches your situation. Look what happens when it gets shrinkwrapped. https://imgur.com/a/SH9owCX The closest surface to the farthest vertex is the one where it has reached in the image. So to actually make it reach the other side of the sphere you have to add curvature to your curves. (I apologize once again that I made you go through the trouble of uploading this large file.)

Comment: No worries! Thanks for the information. This helps.